# Prove that $F(x,y)=f(x-y)$ is Borel measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $A$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$, let $s(A)=\{ (x,y)\in \Bbb R \times \Bbb R :x-y\in A\}$. I already showed: If $A\in \Bbb B$ (Borel measurable set), then $s(A)\in \Bbb B \times \Bbb B$.

I want to use this to prove that if $f$ is a Borel measurable function on $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, then the function $F$ defined by $F(x,y)=f(x-y)$ is measurable with respect to $\Bbb B \times \Bbb B$. Could someone help to provide a proof please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any Borel set $B$
$$
F^{-1}(B)=\{(x,y):F(x,y)\in B\}=\{(x,y):f(x-y)\in B\}=\{(x,y):x-y\in f^{-1}(B)\},
$$
and $f^{-1}(B)$ is Borel, the statement that you already showed implies that the above set is Borel (in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Do you mean that $F^{-1}(B)$ is borel implies $F(B)$ is borel?

Comment: No. $F$ is Borel-measurable iff $F^{-1}(B)$ is Borel for every Borel $B$.

Comment: But isn’t it that if we have $B$ as a Borel set, then $F^{-1}(B)$ is borel already. This means we don’t need the statement I already showed?

Comment: And after knowing that $F^{-1}(B)$ is borel, do I still need to show $F$ is borel or is this trivial?

Comment: That is the $definition$ of F being Borel.

Answer (score 0):

Compositions of Borel measurable functions are Borel measurable. In this case you have a Borel measurable function composed with a continuous function, and a continuous function is of course Borel measurable.