# $F(x,y)=f(x-y)$ is Borel measurable - first part of proof

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose $A$ is a subset of $R$, let $s(A)={(x,y)∈R×R: x−y ∈ A}$.
>   How do you show that if $A∈B$ (Borel measurable set), then $s(A)∈B×B$.

This is part of a larger quest to show that $F(x,y)=f(x-y)$ is Borel measurable when $f$ is Borel measurable that can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771683/prove-that-fx-y-fx-y-is-borel-measurable).

Comment: $(x,y) \mapsto x-y$ is continuous, so for open $A$, $s(A)$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x,y)=x-y$. Clearly $g$ is continuous and Borel measurable. So $F^{-1}(A)=g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}(A)$ is Borel set if $A$ is Borel set. Thus $F$ is Borel measurable.